# Create VIEW (count duplicate values in column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

I have little project with SQL database which has table with some column.

**Question**: How create View in SQL Server, which count how many duplicate values I have in column and show that number in next column.

Here below you can see result which I want to take.

```
|id|name|count|
|1 |tom |     |
|2 |tom |     |
|3 |tom |     |
|  |    |  3  |
|4 |leo |     |
|  |    |  1  |
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should google and use COUNT for this.

Comment: Hello guys! Well my main problem is that I need to create VIEW. Of course its not so hard to do my tast with SQL request like SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS count FROM requests GROUP BY name ORDER BY count DESC; So do have any helpfull ideas?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view is simply a select statement with the words `CREATE VIEW AS` before the `SELECT`. This allows for example, 1 person (DBA) to maintain (create/alter) complex views, while another person (developer) only has the rights to select from them.

So to use @Stidgeon's answer (below):

```
CREATE VIEW MyCounts 
AS
SELECT name, COUNT(id) AS counts
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

and later you can query

```
Select * from MyCounts where counts > 1 order by name
```

or whatever you need to do. Note that `order by` is not allowed *in* views in SQL SERVER.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Thanks for your answer! Have a nice day! =)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want to count how many entries you have for each 'name', in which case you just need to do a simple COUNT query:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
  SELECT name, COUNT(id) AS counts
  FROM table
  GROUP BY name
```

The output in your case would be:

```
name    counts
--------------
Tom       3
Leo       1
```

Comment: Hello man! Well your answer is the same which I wrote in one of my comment before. I need VIEW in SQL server. I hope you understand what I mean cause I know SQL request.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with `grouping sets`:

```
select id, name, count(*)
from t
group by grouping sets ((id, name), (name));
```

The `group by` on `id, name` is redundant; the value should always be "1".  However, this allows the use of `grouping sets`, which is a convenient way to phrase the query.

Comment: Hello man! It`s not something new for me. It seems like you dont understand me. I need VIEW in SQL server. I hope you understand what I mean.